# Delphi timer more precise than milliseconds

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, timer

I've got a program in Delphi which takes in frames from an external application in 25 hertz (25 times per seconds) and then converts it to 60 hertz (60 frames per second) by creating 1-2 extra frames. I need to output these extra frames by continuously building a frame buffer and outputting the frames from here from a separate thread. The problem is that 1000/60 is 16.66667 which means I can't just send the frames in a "interval" on 16 or 17 milliseconds, I need it to be more precise. How do I do this in Delphi/Windows?

Comment: see https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/a-better-timer-for-a-delphi-programmer/

Comment: looks like you need `TStopWatch` - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch

Comment: Use a timer of 1ms, send two frames at 17ms and then one at 16ms.

Comment: @Sertac A standard timer is not accurate enough for a resolution of 1 ms

Comment: @iamjoosy - Obviously don't use a standard timer.

Comment: What you need is a "performance timer". (See the answer of David Heffernan on this.) You also have to note, that the timer precision is a lot less than 1 ms. It's accuracy is seemingly 1 ms but it changes in lot larger periods.

Comment: Original timings for source frames are already sacrificed, which is 40ms per frame, for the sake of additional extrapolated frames. I'm quite confident that a multimedia timer and a frame rate switching between 16-17ms is sufficient for this application.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [multimedia timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743609.aspx) via the Win32 API [`timeSetEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757634.aspx) or [`CreateTimerQueueTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682485.aspx) function.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that these ones only measure with milliseconds accuracy.

Comment: A few words on how this compares to TStopWatch ? (why is it better?)

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to make use of both of the following:

1. The high resolution timer. This is available through the [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644904.aspx) Win32 function, and also wrapped by the Delphi [`TStopwatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) type.
2. A [waitable timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms687012.aspx). This allows you to set a due date in the future and have your thread block, and be woken at the due date.

Both of these have higher resolution than the GUI timer, and should suffice for your needs. Read an overview here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644900.aspx

Comment: Waitable timers are based on the same kernel's thread scheduler clock facility, thus isn't more accurate unless you [`NtSetTimerResolution`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/source/usermode/undocumented%20functions/time/ntsettimerresolution.html), see http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=272