# How to restart a timer's ontimer event Delphi

Tags: delphi, timer

Everywhere on the internet people say the way to restart a timer is by doing the following, however this only seems to "pause" the timer and once its re-enabled it carries on from where it stops:

```
timer1.enabled:=False;
timer1.enabled:=True;
```

The following should never display the message if the timer restarts, and yet it does:

```
procedure TForm1.restarttimer;
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  restarttimer;
  showmessage('Hello');
end;
```

Is there a way to restart the timer in a way that the Ontimer event itself restarts from its first line? ie. The showmessage in the code above would never display.

Comment: Unfortunately, your mental model about how Delphi and Windows work is fundamentally flawed. The current behaviour is certainly the expected one. Remember that Windows applications use a message loop and that a timer works by asking the OS to generate `WM_TIMER` messages. If you want to "restart" a function, you can for instance put its body in a loop and then simply call `Continue`. Don't forget to `Break` at the end. But this has nothing to do with timers.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you buy or download a good book about programming in general and Delphi programming in particular. That way you will learn the basic concepts you need to understand your programs.

Comment: You should probably describe what you want to do with, or why you need the resettable timer. There's probably a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: https://www.embarcadero.com/resources/white-papers?aldSet=en-GB

Comment: The "reset" code does only work "outside" the timer. But when you call it from the OnTimer event, it's to late already!

Comment: We are not "all grumpy man" :). I asked you to explain why you need to reset or stop and restart your timer. If this is related to your game of your previous question, you can just as well let the timer tick all the time and only prevent the action that the timer normally triggers. There are several other options too. If you only would explain the actual reason for why you want to stop/restart the timer.

Comment: @TomBrunberg seems like everyone is just roasting me in the comments. It just seems everyone on this platform overcomplicates things. i want to restart the timer because the ontimer event runs through an array, and i need to change the length of the array. so ultimately the timer needs to stop, array is changed, and the timer RESTARTS from line 1 and not continue where it left off. My goal is to use the delphi knowledge of our highschool curriculum and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to reset the timer so that if say it was counting 1 min and something else happened during that which needs to make it count another 1 min, you don't want it to count just the rest of the time that was remaining

according to https://www.delphigroups.info/2/6d/169892.html

> The TTimer restarts when you
>
> - change Enabled from false to true
> - set a *different* non zero Interval
> - set a non nil OnTimer event, even with the same value as before.

I see you tried the first and you say it doesn't work, but seems you're thinking wrongly that the timer is a countdown like say in Javascript, whereas it is an interval counter that you don't need to restart in the event handler (like you'd do in a countdown one to make it behave like an interval-repeating counter)

Comment: Thanks! Actually the ontimer event cycles through a dynamic array every 20ms, so when the length of the array is changed, the timer needs to stop, wait for the array to rebuild itself and then restart from line 1 so that the for loop in the ontimer event uses the new array.

Comment: @SlothsDontSleep TTimer events don't occur faster than about every 60 ms, so it won't work as fast as you want.

Comment: @not in this case, changing the speed from 20 to 50ms makes the images move half as fast

Comment: for more accuracy can see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979594/delphi-timer-more-precise-than-milliseconds